# OpenLayers: disable selection from label of feature

Tags: openlayers

I have a feature with a circle and a text attribute. The text attribute is displayed via a text-style above the circle center.

The current behavior:
I can select feature from text style label.

The wanted behavior:
I want to disable selection of feature from text style label

Is it possible to create such behavior?

Comment: One way would be to have separate layers for image and label and use a filter on the select https://codesandbox.io/s/cluster-9qw44

Comment: thank you very much it s work like a charm